# AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '<application ID>

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, active-directory

We following the v2 of the OAuth2 of Microsoft Code grant flow as documented in the following,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

After we created an application in App Register under Microsoft Azure, and try to get the code from the following url

https://login.microsoftonline.com/concept4.net/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://postman-echo.com/get&response_mode=query&scope=profile%20openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read&state=skip_get_token2&prompt=consent

Then we got the following error

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '' named 'c4app2019'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: 46424a2f-a3a2-45da-8902-888f5ca61c00\r\nCorrelation ID: 49d0a6ad-e158-4bc9-97b8-a6391c6470bb\r\nTimestamp: 2019-12-11 07:51:31Z","error_codes":[65001],"timestamp":"2019-12-11 07:51:31Z","trace_id":"46424a2f-a3a2-45da-8902-888f5ca61c00","correlation_id":"49d0a6ad-e158-4bc9-97b8-a6391c6470bb","suberror":"consent_required"}

Any idea what permission we need to grant to our application?

[image]

Comment: Is the enterprise application in this tenant `concept4.net`? Could you try it with the tenant id?

Comment: Yes, the application is under concept4net, Use tenant instead of concept4.net, the same error return.

Comment: Try to remove the `&prompt=consent` parameter in the url.

Comment: BTW, if I use incorrect domain (other than concept4.net) to get the code, it will said my "More information required" for my account, If I do it to get token, it will say my application cannot find in the directory "xxx"

Comment: After remove the prompt=consent, it won't prompt me to accept connect, but the same error return when I try to get token by the returned code

Comment: Try to use the admin account to grant admin consent.  
  `GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/adminconsent?
  client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
  &state=12345
  &redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
  &scope=
  https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.read 
  https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.send`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin

Comment: What scope should I ask them to grant me in order to get token from code through the token endpoint? As show in my uploaded image, we have already grant those permission by our administrator. I copy the scope from the Microsoft OAuth2 document with the scope = profile%20openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read.

Comment: I just run @TonyJu's link with the scope = https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.read https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.send, I still get the error when I try to get the token

Comment: To locate your issue, please provide the screenshot like step2(App registrations->your application->API permissions). And the value of scope you used to get code/token.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can not reproduce your issue on my side. Here are my steps for your reference.

1.Create an application with `User.Read` and `profile` permissions.

[image]

2.Since the permissions I added don't need admin consent, so I can consent by the first time I login.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=59437d85-46f8-409c-8211-b3db91a8b0e5
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
&state=12345
```

3.Get the token by using the code I got from step2

[image]

To locate your issue, please provide the screenshot like step2(App registrations->your application->API permissions). And the value of scope you used to get code/token.

Comment: Thanks Tony, it seems working now. However the token I got seems don't contain the refresh token. Any thing we have missed ( e.g. grant type)?

Comment: @raymond.mh.ng To get refresh token, just add offline_access to the scope `offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read`

Answer (score 2):

In case it's helpful to anyone, I was running into the same problem using the magical AzureServiceTokenProvider class from the Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.1.3.1 package. Very simple code

```
var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string token = tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/8a0bec0f-x-x-x-x").GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // Application ID URI
```

My error message was

AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID **'d7813711-9094-4ad3-a062-cac3ec74ebe8'**. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

I couldn't find this d7813711 guid anywhere in my Azure AD. After looking into how this class works in a decompiler, it turns out when you don't specify an app ID, the class defaults to this guid. Maybe this guid is valid across tenants in Azure? To fix the issue so you can get a token for your app, simply add this as an authorized client application.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Additional test 1]
Step 1: 
I have create another app the use less API permission, which has the same issue

[image]

Step 2:
Get code by the following url
https://login.microsoftonline.com/concept4.net/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=15bf7752-....-c51cd145174c&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://postman-echo.com/get&response_mode=query&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read&state=skip_get_token2

and got

[image]

Step 3:

It seems working

[image]

It seems that the scope in Microsoft document for getting code and token is not correct or need some additional permission.

Comment: Hi @raymond.mh.ng

My i know the way to get both access token and refresh token? Awating for your response

Comment: to get refresh token @Justin you need to add offline_access into scopes

Answer (score 1):

We also had this issue. We have updated our graph client to a newer version. We have done the following steps:

- Revoke all admin consent
- Remove all permissions
- Add removed permissions back
- Grant admin consent

I hope this will help someone with troubleshooting.