# Azure registered app error: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-oauth

We´re trying to get the token for Oauth using the official docs request:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id='my client id'
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&code='my auth code obtained in previous auth request'
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret='my client secret'
```

But when we make the request it responds with this error:

```
AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'mya app id' named 'my app name'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource"
```

Thing is, we already gave them this permissions on Azure portal AD and app registration even with the admin consent but still:

[image]

is there any permission missing there ?, any clue about this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **I have tried in my environment and got the access token successfully.
> Please check whether you followed the same steps as below:**

***1) Go to Azure portal -> Azure AD -> App registrations -> Your app -> Authentication -> check the below options -> Save.***

[image]

***2) To resolve the error, make sure to grant below **Api permissions** along with permissions you have given:***

[image]

***3) To get the token, I used postman by giving parameters like below:***

[image]

***4) I successfully got the token like below:***

[image]

After every change, try **refreshing** your Azure Portal and Postman.

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code)

[azure - AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID ' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282141/aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-consented-to-use-the-application)

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer, already added those 3 new permissions, checked the boxes you marked and did exactly the same request on postman but got the same error, any other idea about what could I be missing ?

Comment: After getting that error whatever changes we do in Azure Portal, those are not getting reflected in Postman. I tried creating new application and assigned all those permissions, got token successfully without any error. Try to do same and check if it helps!

Comment: Worked like a charm !, thank you !!

Comment: Glad it helped....Tqs for the update !!