# Generate Bearer Token using Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I have Web API built in .net framework 4.6. I secure my API using Azure AD. For the purpose of development, I need to generate token so I can use it for testing and debugging. How can I generate token from Microsoft Graph that I can use to authenticate to my API?

I tried this [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/token) endpoint but the token it generates is not valid. I get 401 using the token from that endpoint.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frlP8.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error **"401 unauthorized"** usually occurs when you missed giving **`resource parameter`** while generating access token.

If that's the case, you will still get the access token but when you are using the token to authenticate to your API, you will get **"Invalid token"** error.

**To resolve the error, please include below parameters while generating access token:**

- Make sure to include **`resource parameter`** and other required parameters like below:

[image]

- **I tried in my environment**, after including the above parameters, I got the access token successfully like below:

[image: image2]

If the above solution does not work, try with different **`grant_type`** parameter.

For more information, please **refer** below links:

[401 Unauthorized Error–Azure Active Directory (AD) – Microsoft Azure Articles.. (wordpress.com)](https://azuretrendz.wordpress.com/2019/10/05/401-unauthorized-error-azure-active-directory-ad/).

[Getting Access Token for Microsoft Graph Using OAuth REST API - DZone Security](https://dzone.com/articles/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oau)

[Azure registered app error: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71945646/azure-registered-app-error-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-consented-to-use-t/71952605#71952605)

Comment: I got the access token but when using that token I got access denied in my API

Comment: Could you please provide the screenshot of parameters you gave in Postman for token?

Comment: I updated my post and added sample parameters in Post