# Get an Azure Active Directory token as a user

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, access-token, bearer-token

I want to be able getting access token while I act as a user (meaning I only have username and password).
In all the relevant topics I only see that they try getting the token as administrator of the application (for example, in order to know the clientId), but can I do the same while acting as the user of the application?

Comment: Could you give more details on what you are trying to achieve ? When you request a user token, you still need to specify the application you're requesting the token for.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the application as a user (maybe by the url)?

Comment: yes you can specify the `client_id` parameter, See the link for the ROPC flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request.

Comment: But what if I don't have the ```client_id``` parameter? Because I only use the application and don't have any access to it

Comment: A token is valid for an application=scope so you need the client_id / resource_uri. AAD needs to know which application you re trying to get a token for.

Comment: And as I understand I can find out the ```client_id``` only if I the one that register the application on Azure, right?

Comment: you should ask the person who register the app to give you the client_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***As suggested by **[@Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4167200/thomas)**, you can make use of ROPC flow.***

In order to get access token as a user, you still need to know values of **`client_id`** and **`tenant_id`** along with your UPN and password.

**Client_Id** - Your Application ID

**Tenant_Id** - Your Directory ID

You can get these values from the person who registered the application by:
***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Your Application -> Overview***

[image]

After getting those values, make use of **Postman** to generate the access token.

For that, **`POST`** an HTTP request like below that need **`tenant_id`** and parameters like below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

- In Postman, Go to **Authorization** tab and select type as **`Oauth2.0`**
- Visit  **Headers** tab and include **`Content-Type`** key with value as ***application/x-www-form-urlencoded***
- In **Body** tab, include parameters like client_id, grant_type, username, password and scope as below:
  [image]
- Make sure to grant admin consent to required API permissions defined in scope before sending the request.
- Now, send the request and you can get the access token successfully like below:
  [image]

To know more in detail, please refer below **links**:

[Sign in with resource owner password credentials grant - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request)

[Azure registered app error: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71945646/azure-registered-app-error-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-consented-to-use-t/71952605#71952605)