# Azure AD check if auth token is valid

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I am developing a backend Web API for react SPA. The react SPA will do the authentication with the Azure AD, and send the auth token to Web API.

I need to know what are the API available from Azure AD which I can use to validate the auth token? I know there is graph APIs (https://aka.ms/ge) but do we have any Azure AD API to validate auth token.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of validation?

Comment: Much better to use ready-to-use SDK like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-active-directory/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @GauravMantri validate the auth token that react app is sending to my API, whether the auth token is expired or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of **[Postman API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71997849/get-an-azure-active-directory-token-as-a-user/72008042#72008042)** to generate the token and you can find **`expiration time`** in the response along with token like below:

[image]

**To validate the auth token,** you can make use of [JSON Web Tokens - jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).

- After generating the auth token, you can paste the token in the above link and **decode** it.
- Usually, the **decoded token** has sections like below:

  - **header**: It includes **`alg`** which specifies the type of algorithm used to digitally sign the token.
  - **payload**: It includes information about audience, scopes, expiration details, app details etc.
  - **verification signature**: It includes the digital signature of the token that was generated by Azure AD’s private key.

**To check the token expiration**, you can find **[`expires_in`](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#token-expiration-exp-claim)** variable under payload section of decoded token.

[image]

You can check the below **references** to know more in detail:

[Validate Azure Active Directory (AD) generated OAuth tokens (voitanos.io)](https://www.voitanos.io/blog/validating-azure-ad-generated-oauth-tokens?msclkid=0ab5da75cf3011ec82f37bd240dd7e43)

[How to verify token in Azure Active Directory – tsmatz (wordpress.com)](https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2016/03/08/azure-ad-msa-v2-endpoint-validate-id_token/)