# Microsoft Azure CLI is giving me an access token without a refresh token. How do I get an access token that has a refresh token?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, kubeconfig

I'm trying to get AKS credentials set up for a gitlab-runner environment. I can get a basic kubeconfig with `az aks get-credentials -n mythingname -g myresourcegroup -f kubeconfig` but the resulting kubeconfig doesn't have access or refresh tokens.

Using the Azure CLI command `az account get-access-token` gets me an access token, but it doesn't come with a refresh token.

I've looked around and I either can't find an answer or can't find the right google search terms to find the answer. Microsoft's own documentation for Azure CLI is unenlightening on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Please **note** that using **`az account get-access-token`** command, you won't be able to retrieve **refresh token**.

With that command you can get **access token** only like below:

[image]

Azure CLI performs the **token refreshing automatically**. So, it won't generate refresh token separately. Please check the below ***GitHub*** blog:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/6234#issuecomment-387848841

***If you particularly want to retrieve refresh token, try registering an Azure AD App and use **Postman API** to retrieve refresh token and access token like below:***

[image]

For more information, please **refer** below links:

[Add login refresh command · Issue #6234 · Azure/azure-cli · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/6234#issuecomment-387848841)

[Microsoft identity platform refresh tokens - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/refresh-tokens)

[Azure registered app error: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71945646/azure-registered-app-error-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-consented-to-use-t/71952605#71952605)