# "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '' named 'PowerBI'. Send an interactive authorization request

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory, postman, powerbi-api

i'm trying to send a request to a PowerBi API using Postman to do sth but i'm stuck at getting the token for it and got the following error:

[image]

then i tried to follow this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282141/aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-consented-to-use-the-application), which suggested Authorization first. The result that i got was an HTML page instead of a Code.

[image]

i have already given all the Permissions needed for this, although without Granting the Admin permissions, which to my knowledge is not necessary here.

[image]

i also have added postman as Redirect URI.

[image]

posting these images because i suspect that something might be wrong here.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried in my environment with same credentials got an similar error:***

[image]

***Postman:***

[image]

> "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '' named 'PowerBI'. Send an interactive authorization request

The above error occurs when you do not have permission as  ***Grant admin consent is not done***.

Please make sure to grant admin consent to your application API.
***In your azure portal -> Api permission under manage -> add permission->Grant admin consent***

[image]

After grant permission to the all API's/permission name I got an successfull token both access and bearer token:

[image]

[image]

***Reference:***

[How to Call the Power BI REST API from Postman - Carl de Souza](https://carldesouza.com/how-to-call-the-power-bi-rest-api-from-postman/#:%7E:text=First%2C%20follow%20the%20instructions%20here%20to%20register%20an,use%20to%20authenticate%20with%20the%20Power%20BI%20API.)